# How can I add options to the same menu from separate apps script files?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two separate apps script files for a project. `file1.gs` and `file2.gs`.

In `file1.gs`, I create a menu like this:

```
// file1.gs
function updateBalance() { ... }

const menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom');
menu.addItem('Update balance', 'updateBalance');
menu.addToUi();
```

Now in `file2.gs`, I want to add to the menu that was already created by `file1.gs`.

How can I do that? There doesn't appear to be any type of "find menu" function in [the apps script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui). There is only a function to create a menu.

How do I solve for `<WHAT HERE?>` in this example?:

```
// file2.gs
function calculateTotals() { ... }

// How can I find the menu that was already created by file1.gs here?
const menu = <WHAT HERE?>
menu.addItem('Calculate Totals', 'calculateTotals');
```

Comment: In your situation, the files of `file1.gs` and `file2.gs` are included in the same Google Apps Script project? Or, each file is included in each Google Apps Script project? And, in your script, `menu` is used as the global variable?

Comment: @Tanaike These are two files in the same apps script project.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `These are two files in the same apps script project.`, I understood that your 2 files are put in the same Google Apps Script project. But, I couldn't understand whether `menu` is required to be used as the global variable.

Comment: @Tanaike No, it doesn't need to be global. I mean, if you can tell me how to make it a "global" variable that's shared between two files, then that would be one solution. But I'm looking for a way to use the Spreadsheet UI API to find a menu that already exists.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `No, it doesn't need to be global.`, when I saw your showing script, I thought that `menu` is declared as the global variable. I apologize for this. And, I cannot understand `I mean, if you can tell me how to make it a "global" variable that's shared between two files, then that would be one solution. But I'm looking for a way to use the Spreadsheet UI API to find a menu that already exists.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Just remove `const menu = <WHAT HERE?>`. As long as `file1` is executed first, `menu` variable is already available in `file2`. You're misunderstanding how files are handled in apps script.

Comment: @TheMaster This does not answer the question. The question is not about how to share variables, it is about how to get an existing menu item from the UI. What is the recommended solution? What is the proper "find menu" API? I hope you didn't mark this question as a duplicate because it's different.

Comment: There's no such api AFAIK, But,  Didn't you say `if you can tell me how to make it a "global" variable that's shared between two files, then that would be one solution`? All your code points to sharing variable across two files. If you [edit] your question to focus  on something different, I'll consider reopening this.

Comment: @TheMaster If there is no solution other than shared variables, then that is the answer and I'm content to leave it closed. Thank you.